# javascript settimeout cleartimeout routine syntax

Tags: javascript, settimeout

This is the code from another thread.  It activates a function only when the user has stopped typing after a set time.

```
var keyupTimer;
function keyUpEvent(){
   clearTimeout(keyupTimer);
   keyupTimer = setTimeout(sendInput,1000); // will activate when the user has stopped typing for 1 second
} 

function sendInput(){
    alert("Do AJAX request");
}
```

It works as is.  But why does it stop working if I put parenthesis to try to pass variables in this line:

```
keyupTimer = setTimeout(sendInput,1000); //original code
```

To

```
keyupTimer = setTimeout(sendInput(),1000); //with just empty ()
```

or

```
keyupTimer = setTimeout(sendInput(var),1000);//or with ('test') or with (var)
```

with the parenthesis, the delay does not occur and the sendInput function is called immediately. Is this the only format for this particular routine?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
keyupTimer = setTimeout(function()
{
     sendInput('test');
},1000);
```

so have an anonymous function as parameter for 'setTimeout'

Answer (score 3):

> keyupTimer = setTimeout(sendInput,1000); //original code

This says "Run sendInput after 1000ms";

> keyupTimer = setTimeout(sendInput(),1000); //with just empty ()

This says "Run sendInput, capture the return value (which should be a function) and run that after 1000ms".

`sendInput` is a function, `sendInput()` is a function **call**.

Comment: Thanks David for the explanation.  So what would be the syntax for "Run sendInput(with parameters) after 1000ms"?

Comment: Additionally, reading-between-the-lines: if what the OP really want is to pass a parameter to the callback function then the best, cross-browser way is to use a closure to capture the variable: `setTimeout(function(){sendInput(var)},1000)`.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument for `setTimeout` is a function reference (i.e. a variable that points to your function). What you provided is a function call. To pass a function with arguments, wrap the function call in an anonymous function. You can pass it directly to `setTimeout` as an argument since JavaScript functions are first-class objects.

```
keyupTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    sendInput(var);
}, 1000);
```

In more verbose, that equals to this:

```
var callback = function() {
    sendInput(var);
}
keyupTimer = setTimeout(callback, 1000);
```

The inline pattern has its advantage that it has access to the scope where the `setTimeout` is called.

If it fits better to you, you could even create a callback factory to pass a function call to `setTimeout` as [@slebetman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/167735/slebetman) pointed out.

```
function callbackFactory (var) {
    return function() {
        sendInput(var);
    }
};
setTimeout(callbackFactory('some_value'), 1000);
```

Comment: Yet another, better, more verbose example is to use a function factory (just like object factory from factory pattern): `function callbackFactory (var) {return function(){sendInput(var)}}; setTimeout(callbackFactory('some_value'),1000);`

Comment: Thank you Torok. It is weird, my previous thank you is not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

it is also possible to use a string containing javascript code, as a first argument to `setTimeout`. however, it is strongly discouraged (see comments)

```
...
/* DON'T DO THIS: */
keyupTimer = setTimeout("sendInput(variable)", 1000) 
...
```

Comment: Not a good idea because 1: it is a slippery slope towards quoting hell, 2: the "string code" has to be recompiled every time, 3: every time you compose code from string Jon Skeet kills a kitten

Comment: Thank you Mykhal.  Let me try that, but I will probably use the long hand method so that I remember why.

Comment: Please do not propagate bad practice as answer!

Comment: @slebetman, @[Török Gábor] thanks for pointing it out, i'll mention it. however, i won't delete my answer, since the question contained: *Is this the only format for this particular routine?*

Comment: +1 from me, it is a valid answer after all and the bad practice part is mentioned. Since it might be useful in certain situations, you cannot simply ignore this possibility just because it's not considered good practice in most of the cases.